# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OrgeMain_d.lib. Trying to set up an ogre3d app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, installation, ogre, ogre3d

I've searched around and can't find anything that relates to my problem.

```cpp
#include "Ogre\ExampleApplication.h"

class Example1 : public ExampleApplication
{
public:
    void createScene()
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Example1 app;
    app.go();

    return 0;
}
```

Steps I've taken:

- added ...\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-7-4\include to the include path of my project.
- added ...\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-7-4\boost_1_42 to the include path of my project.
- added ...\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-7-4\boost_1_42\lib to my library path.
- added ...\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-7-4\lib\debug to my library path.
- linked OgreMain_d.lib and OIS_d.lib

I've also tried it the way the Ogre site teaches you. But I get the same errors. 
Using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: BTW, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the library name is misspelled. It should be OgreMain_d.lib, not OrgeMain_d.lib.